# How to convert <<name>> to $name

Tags: php

I am trying to convert `<<anyVar>>` to $anyVar

It could be `<<name>>` to $name or `<<age>>` to $age or `<<address>>` to $address or combination of these three. so this could be,

```
$value = "<p>Hi this is &lt;&lt;name&gt;&gt; and I am living in &lt;&lt;address&gt;&gt;</p>";
```

Although I have success one way with this code

```
$value = "<p>Hi this is &lt;&lt;name&gt;&gt;</p>";
$value = htmlspecialchars_decode($value);//Hi this is <<name>>
$value = str_replace("<<","$",$value);//Hi this is $name>>
echo $value = str_replace(">>","",$value);//Hi this is $name
```

But it will fail when value comes after htmlspecialchars_decode is `<<name`, not   `<<name>>`

What changes I should change to fix this. Or any other convenient solution.

Thanks

Comment: https://eval.in/515709

Comment: Please elaborate - give example input and output. `<<name` does not equal `<<name>>` so code that expects the latter will fail on the former. Currently your question is too vague to answer beyond guessing

Comment: Are you trying to replace `<<name>>` with the value of `$name` or with the string `"$name"`?

Comment: @JeremyRodi I am trying to replace string

Comment: If you don't mind, can I ask why?

Comment: php will automatically convert its value.

Comment: @LearningMode please update question with 2 or more example: 1) i have this -> i want this; 2) i have this -> i want this; **include complete example that fails**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `preg_replace` like as

```
echo preg_replace('~(&lt;&lt;)(.*?)(&gt;&gt;)~',"$$2",$your_string);
```

Or you can simply use `str_replace` like as

```
echo str_replace(array("&lt;&lt;","&gt;&gt;"),array("$",""),$your_string);
```

As you can use use array within `str_replace` you can simply replace the values with specific value.
Better to use `str_replace` instead of `preg_replace` as regex creates more overhead than string functions

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/1jpRA)

Comment: Thanks a lot I was just looking for this answer

Answer (score 2):

Why not this:

```
echo $value = str_replace("&lt;&lt;name&gt;&gt;", '$name', $value );
```

Comment: Have updated my question , It could be <<name>> to $name or <<age>> to $age

Answer (score 1):

Here , You dont need to use `htmlspecialchars_decode` as `str_replace` will work for you & work with array while you are doing `str_replace` will reduce line of code, try this,

```
$value = "<p>Hi this is &lt;&lt;name&gt;&gt;</p>";
$htmlentites = array("&lt;&lt;","&gt;&gt;");
$desireInput   = array("$", "");
$value = str_replace($htmlentites,$desireInput,$value);
```

Comment: @LearningMode Have you try my answer ? atleast ?

Comment: I think OP didn't tried as he has already tried mine but anyways +1. But try to explain your answer in better way instead what you have used and why your code is working over here

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$replace = str_replace(
array("&lt;&lt;name&gt;&gt;","&lt;&lt;age&gt;&gt;","&lt;&lt;address&gt;&gt;"),
array('$name','$age','$address'),
'$name', $value );

echo $replace;
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
$value = "<p>Hi this is <<name>></p>"; 
preg_match_all('/<<(.*)>>/', $value, $links);
echo '<pre>';
$$links[1][0]=$links[1][0];
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
$name='Changed name';
echo $name;
```

Comment: It just giving the output. "Hi this is <> name "